# Correct rotation with Quaternion

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, rotation, quaternions

I have some problems with a rotating marble.
I've tried it with `Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll` and `Matrix.CreateRotation` but there were some problems, I think it's due to the *Gimbal lock* effect.

So, I've tried using **quaternions** instead, but nothing changed.
When moving on only an axis it works fine, but when the rotation occurs on two different axes the marble still rotates on wrong axes.

Here's my code:

```cs
// declarations
Vector3 Position = Vector3.Zero;
Vector3 Rotation = Vector3.Zero;
Quaternion qRotation = Quaternion.Identity;

AbsoluteBoneTransforms = new Matrix[Model.Bones.Count]; 
Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(AbsoluteBoneTransforms);
```

In the `Update` method:

```cs
Position += speed;
Rotation = speed * MathHelper.ToRadians(-1.5f);

Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Right, Rotation.Z) *
                Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Backward, Rotation.X);

qRotation *= rot;
```

And in the `Draw` method:

```cs
effect.World = AbsoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * 
  Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(qRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
```

What's wrong? Is it wrong to use `Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle` on multiple axes?

**EDIT**

I've tried calculating directly the axis of rotation of my marble, instead of using combination of multiple axes:

```
angle += speed.Length() * angularVelocity;
qRotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Cross(speed, Vector3.Up), angle);
qRotation.Normalize();
```

`angle` is a float that keeps track of the current movement.
This solution doesn't seem to create *Gimbal lock*, but marble rotations aren't correct, it seems that the rotating speed is not constant, but became faster and slower over time, I can't understand why.

If I "concatenate" the quaternions I get every frame using

```
qRotation *= Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Cross(speed, Vector3.Up), angle)
```

the *Gimbal lock* effect is still visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've tackled that:

I'm assuming `speed` is a vector representing the direction the ball is rolling and whose magnitude represents the rate it is traveling in that direction.

```
Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(speed, Vector3.Up);
float angle = speed.Length();//factor by delta time if neccesary

Quaternion rotationThisFrame = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(axis, angle * (1/radiusOfBall));
```

then you can concatenate that to your qRotation. Also, you may need to normalize your quaternion after concatenation.

Update: The correct answer to this question/thread was reversing the order that quaternions concatenate in. With respect to XNA, matrices combine left to right, quaternions combine right to left.

Comment: It seems that nothing really changed, if the rotation occurs on only one axis it works fine as before, but when involving two axes something goes wrong.

Comment: `qRotation` appears to represent the marble's current orientation. To that orientation, you are combining just the rotation that occurred since last frame with your `Quaternion.CreateFrom...()`. So the angle used in that `CreateFrom...` should represent just the angular motion since the last frame. But it kind of looks like your `angle` (with the +=) is trying to represent the overall angle, which doesn't look right. `angle` should just be the amount of rotation since the last frame.

Comment: It's like in my example, for `angle`, I mean it as `angularChangeSinceLastFrame`.

Comment: Yes, but if I combine multiplying `qRotation` with the previous one, and I use `angle` since the last frame nothing really change, as I wrote in the first comment, and the *gimbal lock* effect is still visible. 
The solution I've added to my question was the only one I've found to avoid it, but it does something wrong with the rotation. I think I can't work it out.

Comment: I'll work on a demo project to sort out the relationship between translational velocity to rotational velocity.

Comment: Rotational velocity depends on the translational velocity and the radius of the rotating object, but that's not my problem.

Comment: Sorry if I'm off track a bit. I just realized/remembered while playing with it that Quaternions concatenate in reverse order that Matrices do in Xna. So where you would do a Matrix like `orientation = orientation * rotationToAdd` (or *=), you would do a quaternion like: `orientation = rotationToAdd * orientation`

Comment: Interesting, I have to try this.

Comment: Thank you very much, concatenating quaternions in reverse order was the right solution!

Comment: yay!! glad we got there.